# count number of columns of mysql procedure output

Tags: mysql

I am running a procedure like below.
Procedure name is - stmt

```
call stmt;
execute stmt;
```

how can I count number of columns of this procedure's output?
is there any function to count columns of an output?

Comment: you can use OUT param for this purpose

Comment: what is the way to use OUT param?

Comment: @vim: No. This can only be done using scripting language that calls the procedure and reads resultset. In `PHP` you have [*`mysqli_field_count`*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.field-count.php). In JAVA, you have [*`ResultSetMetadata.getColumnCount()`*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount()).

Comment: @Ravinder hi bro,i am using c# only

Comment: @Ravinder bro u were right ,I just read resultset using c# and its working fine.thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used scripting language c# for counting resultset like given below and this is working fine.

```
string query1 = "call sgwebdb.stmt;execute stmt";

int count1 = DataManager.DatabaseManager
             .GetOrCreateConnection( DataManager.DatabaseManager
                                     .ConnectionType.MySQL )
             .GetData( query1 ).Tables[0].Columns.Count;
```